# URL Rewriting in WordPress

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

How can I rewrite URLs on WordPress?

For example, I have a URL like `sitename.com/?page=<numbers>&id=<numbers>` and I want to rewrite it as `sitename.com/page/id/<other info>`. How can I do that? I don't understand the rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet for an easy solution is to actually use the "Custom Structure" option in your WordPress admin under Settings > Permalinks.

There are a number of other [structure tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) you may use as seen in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

If you're looking for even more customization and manual control, it's actually a pretty complex topic involving editing your .htaccess file.  [This great two part tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) by Stephan Harris covers this topic very well.  (Better than I ever could here on SO).

Comment: So, the rule might be (in my problem) 
`add_rewrite_rule('^([0-9]*)/^([0-9]*)','index.php?page=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]','top')`. Isn't it?

Comment: @apanzett Well, the expression you have there will try to match numerics for the "page" portion.  You might try something like `add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/^([0-9]*)','index.php?page=$matches[1]&id=$matches[‌​2]','top')`.  Notice the slight difference is that the first section will match all strings (since page names are typically words and/or numbers).  I've found [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/) to be a pretty helpful tool for playing with regex.

Comment: And if I have a known page, i'll try something like `^PAGENAME/([0-9]*)/([^/]*)/([0-9]*) => index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&event=$matches[2]&id=$matches[3]` where `page_id` and `id` are only numbers and `event` is string composed?